# Why do I seem able to add two objects that are equal() to each other to a TreeSet

Tags: java, equals, treeset, sortedset

When adding objects to a `java.util.TreeSet`, you'd hope that two equal objects would only exist once when both have been added, and the following test passes as expected:

```
@Test
void canAddValueToTreeSetTwice_andSetWillContainOneValue() {
    SortedSet<String> sortedSet = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.naturalOrder());

    // String created in a silly way to hopefully create two equal Strings that aren't interned
    String firstInstance = new String(new char[] {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'});
    String secondInstance = new String(new char[] {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'});

    assertThat(firstInstance).isEqualTo(secondInstance);
    assertThat(sortedSet.add(firstInstance)).isTrue();
    assertThat(sortedSet.add(secondInstance)).isFalse();
    assertThat(sortedSet.size()).isEqualTo(1);
}
```

Wrap these Strings in a wrapper class, where the `equals()` and `hashCode()` are based solely on the wrapped class, though and the test fails:

```
@Test
void canAddWrappedValueToTreeSetTwice_andSetWillContainTwoValues() {
    SortedSet<WrappedValue> sortedSet = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(WrappedValue::getValue).thenComparing(WrappedValue::getCreationTime));

    WrappedValue firstInstance = new WrappedValue("Hello");
    WrappedValue secondInstance = new WrappedValue("Hello");

    assertThat(firstInstance).isEqualTo(secondInstance); // Passes
    assertThat(sortedSet.add(firstInstance)).isTrue();   // Passes
    assertThat(sortedSet.add(secondInstance)).isFalse(); // Actual: True
    assertThat(sortedSet.size()).isEqualTo(1);           // Actual: 2
}

private class WrappedValue {
    private final String value;
    private final long creationTime;

    private WrappedValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.creationTime = System.nanoTime();
    }

    private String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    private long getCreationTime() {
        return creationTime;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof WrappedValue)) return false;
        WrappedValue that = (WrappedValue) o;
        return Objects.equals(this.value, that.value);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(value);
    }
}
```

[The JavaDoc for `TreeSet.add()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#add-E-) states what we'd expect:

> Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present. More formally, adds the specified element `e` to this set if the set contains no element `e2` such that `(e==null ? e2==null : e.equals(e2))`. If this set already contains the element, the call leaves the set unchanged and returns `false`.

Given my assertion that the two objects are `equal()`, I'd expect this to pass. I'm working on the assumption that I'm missing something mindnumpingly obvious, unless `TreeSet` *doesn't* actually use `Object.equals()`, but uses something that's near enough the same in the vast majority of cases.

This was observed using JDK 1.8.0.60 - I've not had chance to test other JDKs yet, but I'm presuming there's some "Operator Error" somewhere...

Comment: My actual use-case is for a cache that sorts by an Optional ZonedDateTime field, but falls back to insertion order using the `System.nanoTime()`.

Comment: If equals and your comparator look at different fields, why would they behave in a compatible way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the comparator given to sort the set is incompatible with the `equals` method of `WrappedValue`. You are expecting the `SortedSet` to behave like a `Set`, but it doesn't do so in this case.

From [`SortedSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html):

> Note that the ordering maintained by a sorted set [...] must be *consistent with `equals`* if the sorted set is to correctly implement the `Set` interface. [...] This is so because the `Set` interface is defined in terms of the `equals` operation, but a sorted set performs all element comparisons using its `compareTo` (or `compare`) method, so two elements that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the sorted set, equal. The behavior of a sorted set *is* well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the `Set` interface.

Put another way, the `SortedSet` only uses the comparator you gave in order to determine if two elements are equal. The comparator in this case is

```
Comparator.comparing(WrappedValue::getValue).thenComparing(WrappedValue::getCreationTime)
```

which compares the value and then the creation time. But since the constructor of `WrappedValue` initializes an (effectively) unique creation time with `System.nanoTime()`, no two `WrappedValue` will be considered equal by this comparator. Therefore, as far as the sorted set is concerned

```
WrappedValue firstInstance = new WrappedValue("Hello");
WrappedValue secondInstance = new WrappedValue("Hello");
```

are two distinct objects. Indeed, if you modify a little the constructor to add a `long creationTime` parameter, and give the same time to both instances, you'll notice the "expected" result (i.e. the sorted set will only have a size of 1 after adding the two instances).

So there are 3 solutions here:

1. Fix the `equals` and `hashCode` methods and let them compare both the value and the time.
2. Only give a comparator comparing the value.
3. Accept the fact that the `SortedSet` doesn't behave like a `Set` in this particular case.

Comment: Thanks - I think the lesson to learn here is that I need to read _all_ of the documentation, and not just double-check the method being called. The best solution for my use case is probably to fix the comparator.

Answer (score 1):

Your equals (which only considers `value`) is inconsistent with your Comparator which considered `value` and `creationTime`.

I assume you have two objects with the same value so they are equals true but different creationTimes so they are compareTo != 0.